# Where do you report minor glitches in the system? Here?

Tags: bug

That is, assuming it may matter to someone.

For example, I deleted an old question of my mine with no answers; but when I viewed it under Recently Deleted Questions, it showed that it had one (displayed "1" in the answer box).

So I thought for a sec that I had missed it somehow, and that the rule regarding deleting answered questions had changed; but no, it didn't have any formal answers (i.e., answers not in comments).

Anyway, so I undeleted it and redeleted it to recheck the answer box, and it still populated it with "1" even though it was never answered, formally. But it goes back to "0" when undeleted (listed under the Questions tab).

I find little things like this from time to time, but I don't know if anyone else cares or already knows or where I should mention such a thing in any case. Perhaps here since "bug" is a tag.

Comment: Can you link to the question? It may have already deleted answers that you can’t see. Also here is fine for bug reports.

Comment: @Laurel - Oh, I didn't think of that. Maybe it was answered before (besides thoroughly in comments); if so, I can't recall it. I do see deleted answers sometimes, but maybe I don't have enough points for this particular case or whatever. Anyhow, here's the link (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535595/re-subject-verb-intended-infinitive-phrase-could-the-phrase-function-a). I still don't know how to hyperlink in comments; I'm missing something.

Comment: You can certainly report bugs here, CMs (community managers, SE employees) monitor child metas, especially if you use the right tags, like [meta-tag:bug] (or whatever you’re supposed to use). But you’d get a bigger and more immediate audience if you posted on the [Big Meta](https://meta.StackExchange.com). Again, the right tags will improve response time and quality. Screenshots and links would also help people diagnose the issue.

Comment: Funny, nobody has any problem with my questions when I'm all wishy-washy-@ss-kissy. Tone matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using my power of obscenely high rep, I can confirm that there is one answer under your question. It was [deleted from review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/401086), so you can't see it.

This looks like a duplicate of the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) MSE question  [Answers count in "Deleted Recent Questions" page taking into account deleted answers I can't see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193756/323179). The reason this happens is because it's not worthwhile to calculate exactly what answers a user can see under their deleted question. (You can self-delete when there is only a single answer without upvotes, and closed questions with answers can be deleted by high-rep users. Under either of those circumstances, the answers that were deleted because the question was deleted should be visible to the person who asked the question.)

Comment: OIC now. Thanks for the additional info at the end. I don't understand how, or where, I could view answers to questions that I deleted; but maybe that doesn't apply to me specifically. I'll have to take a closer look and research that if necessary. Thanks again.